# how to change Class component to functional component in react native

Tags: react-native

I am new to react native. how To change above code which is in class component to functional component. please help. thanks

```
import { BackHandler } from 'react-native';

constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.handleBackButtonClick = this.handleBackButtonClick.bind(this);
}

componentWillMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButtonClick);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButtonClick);
}

handleBackButtonClick() {
      this.props.navigation.navigate("Browse");

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use can use useEffect hook to get the functionality in useEffect the return function acts componentWillUnmount

code:

```
function handleBackButtonClick() {
    navigation.goBack(null);
    return true;
}

useEffect(() => {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress',handleBackButtonClick);
    return () => {
       BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress',handleBackButtonClick);
    }
}, [])
```

Comment: one more can we use more than one useeffect in functional component

Comment: Yes, you can use more than one useEffect hooks.

Comment: you can use multiple useEffects in a functional component

Comment: @Ketan Ramteke But using this code Its only navigate to previous screen from which I have come. I want to navigate to that screen which I have given to navigation.navigate. please help. thanks. means I want to navigate to "browse" screen

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66061426/how-do-i-handle-hardware-back-button-of-android-to-screen-which-i-given-to-navig

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to watch the documentary of useEffect (Hooks). For now, this code would be the conversion from Class to Functional. As you notice we can write unmount and mount functions inside the useEffect

```
import { BackHandler } from "react-native";

const MyNewFunctionalComponent = ({ navigation }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    function handleBackButtonBlick() {
      navigation.goBack();
    }
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', handleBackButtonClick);
    return function cleanup() {
      BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', handleBackButtonClick);
    };
  }, [])

  return (
    // Display what you want here
    null
  )
}
```