# How Do I handle Hardware back button of android to screen which I given to navigation.navigate in react native

Tags: react-native, navigation

I am new to react native. I want that when I press android Hardware back button. I navigate to page or screen which name I have given To that navigation.navigate

I have made this

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.handleBackButtonClick = this.handleBackButtonClick.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButtonClick);
}

componentDidUnmount() {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButtonClick);
}

handleBackButtonClick() {
    this.props.navigation.navigate("Browse");
    return true;
}
```

But using this code Its only navigate to previous screen from which I have come. I want to navigate to "browse" screen. please help. thanks

Comment: You should try ComponentWillUnmount instead of ComponentDidUnmount

Comment: Yes I had Try this also But Same result

Comment: I used the code for disabling the back button and it worked fine. Can you please check it for that, to make sure other things are working.

Comment: Means My all screen Are in Drawer navigation

Comment: I navigate All trought drawer

Comment: Checked this code on stack Navigator and it works fine.

Comment: Yes Its work fine on stack I know But I Want IT works in drawer

Comment: can you please upload the code of your navigators

Comment: Please upload whole code. I tried it with drawer navigator also and it works fine.

Comment: what You think what causes of this problems. just tell me. in which case this is happen

Comment: I don't know that is why i am asking to upload code to check that if that is alright. Till now, i checked the same code (just copy pasted it ) in both stack as well as drawer navigator and it is working fine.

Comment: https://lifesaver.codes/answer/trouble-handling-android-hardware-back-button This may help